# Is it possible to use past progressive with time adverb

Tags: past-tense

Is it possible to use past progressive tense with time preposition ago in a sentence: " I was just thinking about that 30 minutes ago" or would use simple past?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, native English speakers say things like this all the time.  In fact, I was *just saying it* yesterday.

I'm not sure there's much more to add to answer your question, so here are some examples:

> I was *just talking to her* the other day about whether we should have a party for his birthday.
>
> She was *still writing* furiously when the teacher called the end of the exam.
>
> They were *already traveling to* Europe when they heard the news.

Comment: that is what I thought.. thank you.. but I could still say.. " I just thought about that 30 minutues ago. but it would mean different thing, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AlžbetaČelesová Yes, but only a small difference.  The progressive indicates an action *in progress* at that time.  Sometimes you use this because you want to relate it to another action ("I was talking while he was writing") and sometimes you use it because it makes the listener feel more like a part of the action.